# Pinch zoom uiscrollview only on x-axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

How can i restrict the pinching effect only on X-axis. ?﻿

I've created a ScrollView and added an image into it . I've already done the pinch zoom effect for the UIImageView but i want to restrict the zoom only on X-axis.

Comment: check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423119/uiview-how-do-i-constrain-scaling-to-one-dimension-only

Comment: I've created a color picker and i want to pinch zoom it along x-axis to make the color gradient selection much more easier . How can i do it ?

Comment: I actually want to pinch zoom the color picker view of the below project . Precisely speaking I want to zoom the Inf Color Bar Picker View in the xib file.

And I want to restrict the picker view within the current frame and to pinch zoom only on X-Axis.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5ivu3jrb18tx9m/InfColorPicker-master.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

**1.** Use `UIScrollViewDelegate`
**2.** Implement this function

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0)
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    else
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; 
}
```

Comment: I've created a color picker and i want to pinch zoom it along x-axis to make the color gradient selection much more easier . How can i do it ?