# How to Pinch/Zoom in a UiWebView vertically only not horizontally

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, zooming, pinch

I want to make my webview to be pinched/zoomed vertically only. By zooming the webview I want to make it zommed vertically only but not horizontally.
Does it possible?

Comment: May be it is not possible to zoom any view for a particular axis.. When you zoom a view it will zoom by both x-axis and y-axis. You are asking for only y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView also has UIScrollView as its subclass.

So refer [how-to-lock-the-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-scrollview-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271521/how-to-lock-the-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-scrollview-in-ios) link.

Comment: no it's not same. I have gone through this link. I want to disable horizontal zooming at the time of zooming in a webView

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search, I found others that have blazed the trail before you:
[Custom Pinch Zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531698/implement-custom-zooming-for-a-uiscrollview)

The short answer is No, you can't realistically make an entirely custom pinch zoom like you would like. But, you can easily get the *end* behavior that you are looking for by manually rescaling your content after the automated pinch zoom has been released. It's not as pretty, but if your determined to have a vertical zoom, it might be the best option.