# Can you make your entire application pinch-zoomable?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

Is it possible/safe to make an UIKit based app zoomable globally? (The entire app view is pinch zoomable).

I think it similar with web page (html based app) zoom functionality inside UIWebview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

To achieve this, just add your `UIView` to a `UIScrollView` that covers the whole window.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, 
Btw, this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990458/zoom-uilabel-re-render-font-at-correct-size and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448285/how-do-i-reset-after-a-uiscrollview-zoom/451629#451629 will be helpful to me in my problems.