# Resizing UILabel after zooming ends in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I've read a couple posts here about zooming [Zoom UILabel & Re-render font at correct size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990458/zoom-uilabel-re-render-font-at-correct-size)

but I'm still not getting it.  I have a UIScrollView that just has some UILabel and UIView (colored rectangles) in it.  In the delegate method scrollViewDidEndZooming, I try to do something like:

```
[self.label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16*scale];
```

just to see if the label would look good and scale.  I also tried 16/scale and both do not seem to be correct.  (16 is the size that is set in IB).

Anyone have any thoughts on how to zoom/scale properly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do a scale of the font, you need scale the frame too