# Blurry UITextView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitextview, blurry

I am having problems with a blurry UITextView in a UIScrollView so I created a simple little app that just have a ScrollView that holds on to a view that in turn has a UITextView on it. Below code is all the code I have for setting it up. If you zoom in the text is blurry. I have seen other post about this and the suggestions have been to set the contentScaleFactor on the UITextView. However, does doesn't work either. Another suggestion is making sure the frame of the UITextField is not in between pixels...which you can see in my example the frame is on whole pixels.

So I am at a loss for ideas of how to try to make the text render crisp.

If anyone have any ideas please let me know.

Thanks,

Peter

```
@implementation SIAppDelegate
{
    UITextView *textView;
    float originalFontSize;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   self.viewController = [[SIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SIViewController"    bundle:nil];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

   //Setting up the scroll view
   UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.viewController.view;
   scrollView.delegate = self;

   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5;
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;

   //Setting up the content view
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.frame];    
   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

   textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(200, 200, 200, 200))];
   textView.text = @"Hello, World";

   [view addSubview:textView];
   [scrollView addSubview:view];

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 2000);


   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}



-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    return scrollView.subviews[0];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
 [scrollView.subviews[0] setContentScaleFactor:scale];

textView.contentScaleFactor = scale;


}

@end
```

Comment: Log every frame - NSStringFromCGRect() - bet something is not integral

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451629/904355)

Looks like the scale factor is the right way to go, but just using the default scale from the scrollview delegate isn't enough to get crisp text.